# WebClient DownloadString stuck

Tags: c#, .net

I have this class that Inheritance `WebClient` :

```
public class WebDownload : WebClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Time in milliseconds
    /// </summary>
    public int Timeout { get; set; }

    public WebDownload() : this(10000) { }

    public WebDownload(int timeout)
    {
        this.Timeout = timeout;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request != null)
        {
            request.Timeout = this.Timeout;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

And in my code i loop over a lot of `Urls` and download the one after one with :

```
string source;
using (WebDownload client = new WebDownload()) // WebClient class inherits IDisposable
{
    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0");
    source = client.DownloadString(url);
}

return source;
```

And i have a problem that sometimes the code stuck on this method:

```
source = client.DownloadString(url);
```

Any idea why it happen? I put a `Timeout` of 10 seconds to stop the request if it fails.

Comment: Maybe try calling them async, or use some kind of managed threading technique would wourk better for you.

Comment: There is also request.ReadWriteTimeout, it defaults to 5min.

Comment: @HanletEscaño: asynchronous operations on HttpWebRequest/Response do not use either Timeout or ReadWriteTimeout. You must set timers and abort asynchronous requests yourself.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy How i can set this ReadWriteTimeout in the webclient?

Comment: The same as you set Timeout, only you need to cast to HttpWebRequest.

Comment: I done it and it's still stuck in some urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DownloadString is getting stuck, please have a try with `DownloadStringAsync`. 
Long running operations should run asynchronously.

```
WebClient w = new WebClient();
w.DownloadStringCompleted += 
                   new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(downloadCompleted);
w.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com"));
```

in this example, the custom method *downloadCompleted* happens when download is finished, you will have the downloaded string available in the `Result` property.

You can use `CancelAsync` to cancel asynchronous operations if needed.

Comment: Can you explain the technical background why an async request is needed here from a *technical perspective*? I am having the same issue right now (coming from the java world though), and in my case, my program needs to wait for the response anyway, there is nothing else going on (no UI-blocking, nothing), just a simple command line tool that does stuff sequentially. Why would I need to change to async? Is this a limitation of the WebClient in .NET? I set the timeout to an hour. Thanks!

Comment: My request takes about 10-12 minutes. What exactly would close(?) the connection during the synchronous call or whatever happens there. In my case, simply nothing happens, no feedback from the downloadString method at all.

Comment: I would also like to know the reasoning behind this. Specifically the "Long running operations should run asynchronously." sounds like a bold statement to me. What makes you say that?